# On concluding affine ness of a connected scheme from the existence of a proper monomorphism to an affine, Noetherian scheme of finite Krull dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory, schemes

Let $X$ be a connected Scheme. Let $Y$ be an affine, Noetherian Scheme of finite Krull dimension. If there exists a proper morphism of schemes $X\to Y$ which is also a monomorphism in the category of schemes , then is $X$ necessarily affine ?

Comment: Proper monomorphisms are closed embeddings: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04XV

Comment: @AlexYoucis: thanks .. let me just make one thing sure , we don't need to assume $X$ is Noetherian for this, right ?

Comment: Correct. $\text{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get this off the unanswered queue.

The point is that if $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of arbitrary schemes, then $f$ is a closed embedding if and only if $f$ is a proper monomorphism. In fact, there are many equivalent definitions of closed embedding in a similar vein. See [Tag04XV](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04XV).

So, if $Y$ is any affine scheme and $X\to Y$ is a proper monomorphism, then $X$ is a closed subscheme of $Y$ and thus affine.